# Entity Framework doesn't delete children, instead sets references to null

Tags: entity-framework, cascading-deletes

I have the following situation:

First the only relevant table/class (all auto generated from DB (MySQL)):

[image: Table]

The relevant part of the edmx file:

```
     <Association Name="navigationitem_ibfk_1">
      <End Role="navigationitem" Type="Model.Store.navigationitem" Multiplicity="0..1">
        <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
      </End>
      <End Role="navigationitem1" Type="Model.Store.navigationitem" Multiplicity="*" />
      <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="navigationitem">
          <PropertyRef Name="id" />
        </Principal>
        <Dependent Role="navigationitem1">
          <PropertyRef Name="navigationitemid" />
        </Dependent>
      </ReferentialConstraint>
    </Association>
```

I think there aren't many more words needed: It's a navigation table, each navigationitem can have children (but it's not a must).

Now when I try to remove a top level item which has a child:

```
context.Remove(topLevelNode);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It deletes the top level node in the DB, but at the child nodes it just sets the `navigationitemid` to `null` (and yes - I have defined on delete cascade in the DB, when I delete it directly there it works).

So what I think it's going on is, that when I delete the parent node, the framework sets all `navigationitemid` of all children to `NULL`, then when the navigation should be saved to the DB it won't cascade the delete because the `navigationitemid` of the children are `NULL`.

What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing one would like to do is define cascade deletes on the association in the context. But trying it I found out that either sql server does not support it or EF needs help:

- Defining cascade delete on the foreign key constraint (using code-first) throws a sql server exception:

  > Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'xxx' on table 'yyy' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. ([See here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843))
- Cascade delete in EF model: now when deleting a parent the child records are not deleted. Even worse: the FK fields are not nullified and the foreign key constraint violation will throw an exception. The remedy is to [load the child collection before deleting the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566440/861716).

Especially when deleting a tree of `navigationitem`s this is not a very attractive option, but I'm afraid it's all you've got at the moment.

Comment: Well for a workaround (or maybe for good) I wrote a recursive function which goes through the tree and deletes all the children.. sad that EF can't do it - almost unbelievable. Thanks anyway for your research.

Comment: Yes, it's a theme that recurs at SO many times in many ways: EF does not support/facilitate recursive tasks. I think the bottom line is that SQL itself is not recursive by nature. SQL revolves around singular set operations - recursive or hierarchical statements are absent or vendor-specific at best (Oracle's START WITH/CONNECT BY, sql server's hierarchyId). So I doubt if EF will support recursiveness any time soon because there is no way to do in in any standard SQL way.

Comment: But I don't think it has something to to with recusrive tasks, since EF does something (it sets all parentid in the children to null), but it's the wrong thing and I mean SQL does it correctly with "cascade delete"...

Comment: I don't know. Cascade delete on the RDBMS level is not supported with self-referencing FK's (in sql server, that is), and apparently EF does not feel the obligation to solve that. It would have to traverse a hierarchy itself which, I can imagine, is deemed to be beyond the scope of an ORM. But EF is developing rapidly. The many issues at SO covering this ground may raise momentum for the ASP.Net team to scratch their heads and do something about it. AFAIK NHibernate does support recursive cascades, although it may cause N+1 queries.